# How to static initialize a Map in Thymeleaf?

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I have the following `thymeleaf` navigation bar html, and would like to shorten it by repeating the link creation with `th:each` from a static `Map`:

```
<div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li th:classappend="${#httpServletRequest.getRequestURI() == '/home' ? 'active':''}">
            <a href="/home">Home</a></li>
        <li th:classappend="${#httpServletRequest.getRequestURI() == '/pax' ? 'active':''}">
            <a href="/pax">Person</a></li>
        <li th:classappend="${#httpServletRequest.getRequestURI() == '/about' ? 'active':''}">
            <a href="/about">About</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The question is: how can I initialize a static `Map` inside the html page, without having to bind to a backend controller? The map should key-value represent the mapping between "url path" and "link name".

In java code this would be:

```
new HashMap<String, String>() {{
   put("/pax", "Person");
}};
```

But how can I achieve this in plain thymeleaf html, without backend code?

Similar to:

```
<li th:each="entry : ${HOW TO HASHMAP}"
    th:classappend="${#httpServletRequest.getRequestURI() == '/'+entry.getKey()' ? 'active':''}">
  <a th:href="'/'+${link.getKey()}" th:text="$entry.getValue()"/>
</li>
```

Answer (score 4):

[Spring expression inline maps](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-inline-maps).  (Spaces between brackets -- `${ {` -- are important, otherwise the expression is interpreted using thymeleaf double bracket syntax.)

```
<li th:each="entry: ${ {home:'Home', pax:'Person', about:'About'} }"
    th:classappend="${#httpServletRequest.getRequestURI() == '/' + entry.key ? 'active' : ''}">
  <a th:href="'/' + ${entry.key}" th:text="${entry.value}"/>
</li>
```

Comment: I was not aware of the mandatory **spaces** between the brackets. That solved it.